# How data gets into HDFS files system

Tags: hdfs

I am trying to understand how data from multiple sources and systems gets into HDF? I want to push web server log files form 30+ systems. These logs are sitting on 18 different servers.

Thx
Veer

Answer (score 0):

You can create a map-reduce job. The input for your mapper would be a file sitting on a server, and your reducer would deduct to which path to put the file in hdfs. You can either aggregate all of your files in your reducer, or simply write the file as is at the given path.

You can use Oozie to schedule the job, or you can run it sporadically by submitting the map-reduce job on the server which hosts the job tracker service.

You could also create an java application that uses the hdfs api. The FileSystem object can be used to do standard file system operation, like writing a file to a given path.

Either way, you need to request the creation through hdfs api, because the name node is responsible for  splitting the file in blocks and writing it on distributed servers.

Comment: Thanks sturcotte06. As I mentioned I have these file distributed over 18 computers. Do I need setup Hadoop Cluster first. I am struggling to understand how a map reduce job can read files sitting on a different server without a supported file system (HDFS) installed on all the computers.

Comment: You do need Hadoop up and running first. If you don't want to install it, you can easily do a parallel application that will read from all sources and that will do a load balancing of log files on all of your 18 servers. On a different note, you could use Apache Flume to apppend your log files into hdfs (or into elastic search if you're looking for an alternative)